# Compare two tables in SQL Server with exceptions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables like this

**Tableyesterday**:

```
Column1 Column2  Column3     Column4 
------------------------------------------------------
John     5584    samsung     2017-08-31 23:43:06.867
Bob      4512    apple       2017-08-31 23:43:06.867
Hana     1881    nokia       2017-08-31 23:43:06.867
Hanz     4866    alcatel     2017-08-31 23:43:06.867
Nicol    48633   android     2017-08-31 23:43:06.867  ---gone
```

**Tabletoday**

```
Column1 Column2     Column3     Column4 
------------------------------------------------------
John     5584       samsung     2017-09-01 23:43:06.867 ---same entry
Bob      4542446    apple       2017-09-01 23:43:06.867 ---change in column2
Hana     1881       halophone   2017-09-01 23:43:06.867 ---change in column3 
Hanz     4866       alcatel     2017-09-01 23:43:06.867 ---same entry
Mark     486654     alcatel     2017-09-01 23:43:06.867 ---new entry
```

I need to select today's changes and insert into tableofchanges. Only these two rows have to be selected:

**Tableofchanges**

```
Bob      4542446    apple       2017-09-01 23:43:06.867
Hana     1881       halophone   2017-09-01 23:43:06.867
```

I created this queries, but I cannot include Column4 in final select. However, if I do select/insert without Column4, I would not see Column4 in the result:

```
insert into Tableofchanges
    select 
        Column1, Column2, Column3 
    from 
        [dbo].[tabletoday]
    except
    select 
        Column1, Column2, Column3 
    from 
        [dbo].[Tableyesterday]
    where  
        tabletoday.Column4 = Tableyesterday.Column4
```

OR

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Tableofchanges] (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4)
    SELECT      
        Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4   
    FROM         
        [dbo].[Tableyesterday]
    WHERE        
        (NOT EXISTS (SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4
                     FROM [dbo].[Tabletoday]
                     WHERE ([dbo].[Tableyesterday].Column1 = Column1) 
                       AND ([dbo].[Tabletoday].Column1 = Column1)  
                       AND ([dbo].[Tableyesterday].Column2 = Column2) 
                       AND ([dbo].[Tabletoday].Column2 = Column2) 
                       AND ([dbo].[Tableyesterday].Column3 = Column3) 
                       AND ([dbo].[Tabletoday].Column3 = Column3)))
```

Thank you so much for fix my queries

Comment: How do you identify a row? Is Column1 the primary key, so that you compare rows with the same Column1 and look for changes in Column2 and Column3?

Comment: Yes but primary key one day can be new and next day can go way.. MARK+NICOL

Comment: Why can you not do SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4 FROM TableToday EXCEPT select Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4 FROM TableYesterday. This should pick up all the rows from today which are different from rows yesterday, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Steve Ford: Yes, you are missing something: you would also select new entries, not only changed ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want records of today where a record with the same key but different attributes exists in yesterday's data. Supposing that your key is `Column1`, the insert statement would be:

```
insert into tableofchanges
  select column1, column2,column3 
  from dbo.tabletoday t
  where exists
  (
    select *
    from Tableyesterday y
    where y.Column1 = t.Column1
    and (y.Column2 <> t.Column2 or y.Column3 <> t.Column3
  );
```

If `Column2` or `Column3` can be null, you'll have to adjust the `WHERE` clause for this, because `<>` doesn't detect changes from or to null.

Comment: Then try to adjust the conditions accordingly. If you have problems with this, come back.

Comment: Thanks for accepting :-) If you want to compare your solution with mine: In standard SQL you would replace `y.column2 <> t.column2` with `y.column2 is distinct from t.column2`, but SQL Server doesn't support this. So you'd write something like `(y.column2 <> t.column2 or (y.column2 is null and t.column2 is not null) or (y.column2 is not null and t.column2 is null))`. This looks clumsy and often we replace null with an impossible value instead: `coalesce(y.column2, -9999) <> coalesce(t.column2, -9999)`.

Answer (score 0):

In this query, take records where date is changed in table today for similar record in table yesterday. Considering Column1 is the primary key. You cannot compare on dates, because date in your column4 changes between today and yesterday. So, pull out

Records which have changes
UNION 
Records which are newly inserted today and were not there yesterday

```
SELECT a.Column1, a.Column2, a.Column3, a.Column4 FROM Tabletoday a INNER JOIN Tableyesterday b ON a.Column1 = b.Column1 
AND (ISNULL(a.Column2,'') <> ISNULL(b.Column2,'') 
OR ISNULL(a.Column3,'') <> ISNULL(b.Column3,''))
UNION 
SELECT a.Column1, a.Column2, a.Column3, a.Column4 FROM @Tabletoday a 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Tableyesterday b WHERE a.Column1 = b.Column1)
```